# Difference in version of python in docker compose services

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, django-channels

I'm trying to make a docker image of my website made with django and channels. I have 4 services: redis, http server, channel worker and daphne server.
However, I have an error on the daphne server.
I've found that between service, there were different python version while the docker fiel is the same

This is my docker-compose.yaml :

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
  web:
    build: ./soundover
    command: bash -c "python --version && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./soundover:/soundover
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  worker_channels:
    build: ./soundover
    command: bash -c "python --version && python manage.py runworker websocket"
    volumes:
      - ./soundover:/soundover
    links:
      - redis

  channels:
    build: ./soundover
    command: bash -c "python --version && daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 soundover.asgi:application"
    volumes:
      - ./soundover:/soundover
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    links:
      - redis
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV WEBAPP_DIR=/soundover

RUN mkdir $WEBAPP_DIR
WORKDIR $WEBAPP_DIR

ADD requirements.txt $WEBAPP_DIR/
ADD manage.py $WEBAPP_DIR/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install git+https://github.com/django/channels.git --upgrade
```

I had the versions displayed and this is the result :

```
web_1             |  Python 3.6.9
worker_channel_1  |  Python 3.6.9
channels_1        |  Python 3.5.7
```

I expect the output 3.6.9 for all services.

Is there a way to force the use of python 3.6 for the service channels(with daphne server) ?

Comment: Please don’t paste external links of screen shots of terminals...especially to very noisy sites.  Just paste the three lines of text from your console into the question.

Comment: Here, I use the same configuration in my Daphen Docker and the Python Version is 3.6.6. Have you tried rebuild your container?

Comment: As @PauloHenrique mentioned, have you tried rebuilding? What exact compose commands did you use and in what order?  When you run `docker-compose up` it will only build the image if one with that name:tag doesn't exist in your local cache. Even though you have the same Dockerfile, compose generates unique image names for each service. Try running `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: @NickRundle it works ! It fixed the channel error but there is a new error on workers `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`. This is a problem of connection between services ?